# How to find if a browser supports History.Pushstate or not?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, hash, pushstate

I want to change URL without without reloading the page. The possible solution I found is

> window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');

but some browser like Firefox 3.5, IE6+ does not support this, so for them solution is

> var uri = window.location.href;

but the issue is how to discover if a browser supports history.pushstate or not?

Is TRY CATCH is the possible solution or any thing else.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
if (history.pushState) {
  // supported.
}
```

Quickest test is to run this in the browser console to see if it's supported:

```
if (history.pushState) { alert('supported'); }
```

Also notice that in FF `typeof(history.pushState)` returns "function", while in IE it returns "undefined"

Comment: With Firefox, when there is no actually history in the push stack (when you are the root of the domain), history.pushState return actually "undefined". I don't know if this is a bug, but it's really annoying.

Comment: Amendment to this answer. Use if(typeof window.history.pushState != 'undefined') to avoid error message on some old mobiles.